# Telegraph equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find a general solution for 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{tt}+au_{t}+bu=c^2u_{xx} & 0< x< L\\ 
u(0,x)=\varphi (x)& 0\leq x\leq L\\ 
u_t(0,x)=\psi (x)& 0\leq x\leq L\\ 
u(t,0)=u(t,L)=0 & t> 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So far, I've done this: $$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$
$$\frac{1}{c^2} \left( \frac{T''}{T}+a\frac{T'}{T}+b \right) = \frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda $$
$$T''+aT'+T(b+\lambda c^2)=0$$
$$X''+\lambda X=0$$
Then I found the solutions to the characteristic equation:
$$r^2+ar+b+\lambda c^2=0$$
$$r_{1,2}=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4(b+\lambda c^2)}}{2}$$ (looking only at the real solutions for simplicity). Therefore, $$T(t)=Ae^{r_1 t}+Be^{r_2 t}$$
$$X(x)=Ce^{\sqrt{-\lambda }x}+De^{-\sqrt{-\lambda }x}$$
From there, I tried to look at the BCs. $u(t,0)=X(0)T(t)$ Therefore, $X(0)=0$, then, $C+D=0$
After that, I tried to look at other BC's but couldn't come up with anything. How should I proceed from here? Any help would be appreciated!